# Alinhar colunas da tabela

Tags: html, css, table

Tenho a seguinte tabela, e gostaria de saber como eu consigo alinhar os valores de acordo com a coluna correspondente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como da pra ver na imagem os valores estão desalinhados, o 9 que é referente a "GP" ele está muito pra direita, como eu posso resolver isso?

```css
.stats table tbody tr td {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-stripped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Jogador</td>
      <td>GP</td>
      <td>PTS</td>
      <td>AST</td>
      <td>OREB</td>
      <td>DREB</td>
      <td>REB</td>
      <td>STL</td>
      <td>BLK</td>
      <td>TO</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>FGM</td>
      <td>FGA</td>
      <td>FG%</td>
      <td>3PM</td>
      <td>3PA</td>
      <td>3P%</td>
      <td>FTM</td>
      <td>FTA</td>
      <td>FT%</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Keome</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>372</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>108</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>272</td>
      <td>65.8</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>24
      </td>
      <td>
        54.2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Poste o código para analisarmos

Comment: Coloquei o código em um bin se não ficaria mt grande https://ghostbin.com/paste/e4cfy

Comment: @Willian, por favor, leia sobre [mcve]. Será mais fácil para nós se você nos passar apenas o código HTML final, gerado pelo PHP, do quê com o PHP junto, pois assim conseguiremos reproduzir seu problema.

Comment: Editei e adicionei ao post, ou se preferir: https://ghostbin.com/paste/nahr8

Comment: O seu exemplo de código não é o mesmo da imagem. Tente adicionar uma borda nas colunas e ver o resultado, pois no teste que fiz aqui tudo parece correto - https://jsfiddle.net/3gkdnrfx/

Comment: O código que você postou não está se comportando como o da imagem que você compartilhou, como o @AndersonCarlosWoss sugeriu, poste um exemplo mínimo verificável para que possamos te ajudar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Você esta praticamente formatando toda a tabela para "left" (esquerda) em seu atual CSS:

```
 .stats table tbody tr td
```

Isso ocorre porque você esta usando `text-align: left;` para `stats table tbody tr td` tente remover a formatação de `td` realizando a formatação separadamente, por exemplo, onde esta:

```
.stats table tbody tr td {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Substitua por:

```
.stats table tbody tr {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Agora crie uma regra CSS apenas para a td, adicione esse código ao seu CSS:

```
td, th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Salve e recarregue a página que tudo deverá funcionar bem, se desejar ajustar ainda mais a centralização, mude de `text-align: left` para `text-align: center` no código CSS de `.stats table tbody tr`